# importing image to django page

Tags: python, django, image

I am trying to attach an image to my page (per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files), but it cannot be displayed: http://prntscr.com/evwern

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/portfolio/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),]
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static '/catalog/static/portfolio/oh_i_ah.jpg' %}" alt="My image" style="width:640px;height:473px;"/>
```

**Path to the image**: mysite/portfolio/catalog/static/portfolio/oh_i_ah.jpg

If I try to open the image in the new tab it throws:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/portfolio/catalog/static/portfolio/oh_i_ah.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You did not specify your app directory name. Need to know the app/directory name to answer your question properly.
2) You did not use 'static' properly.
3) You did not specify whether you are using default django development server or some production server. I am assuming that it's default django development server with DEBUG=True.

**Solution**

*Let's imagine:* You have an app named app0 (let's say you created that with "python manage.py startapp app0") and you have created a directory called "static " inside of that (following default django convention over configuration). Inside of this 'static' directory you have created another directory called 'app0'. So, you are going to put your file inside "/app0/static/app0". So, your file path becomes: "/app0/static/app0/oh_i_ah.jpg"

Now, set STATIC_ROOT properly in the settings.py

In the template file refer the file as {% static "app0/oh_i_ah.jpg" %} (without leading forward slash).

Now, everything will be ok.

Yes, you can put the static files outside of any app directory if you configure STATICFILES_DIRS, STATIC_ROOT in settings.py correctly.

Please properly describe your problem with as much details as possible so that we can help you in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py

```
import os
STATIC_URL = '/portfolio/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```

and

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

in index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static '/portfolio/oh_i_ah.jpg' %}" alt="My image" style="width:640px;height:473px;"/>
```

Comment: "You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the required STATIC_URL setting.

Comment: Don't remove STATIC_URL variable in settings.py

Comment: it still sits there. when I removed STATICFILES_DIRS it went through then and collected al static files, bu the image is still unreachable

Comment: Okey, change the static root path.